# Database Replication MSSQL 2000 to 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, replication

I am trying to replicate a database from SQL server 2000 to 2005 they are located on two different servers both running Windows Server 2003 R2. Im am using SERVER1(SQL2000) as the Transactional publisher and distributor and SERVER2(SQL2005) is the subscriber. I can set up the publication and subscription but when I try to syncronize them I get the following error:

SERVER1-TestReplication-TestReplication-IBSCNVII-ReplicationCNVII_2-99956FE2-402A-48D5-B801-2CBADF12BD3E has server access (reason: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user '', error code 0x5. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 15404)).

Do I need to add my domain user to a certain user group on server? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x5 means "access denied" and that you're not allowed to query active directory user information. Likely, the sql server service account does not have proper domain privileges to perform look ups in AD. This could be caused by an account password simply being expired and therefore not enabling SQL to validate against AD or some other issue like services running as local system and not a domain account.

I would recommend confirming that both SQL servers are using a valid domain account and not something like local system. Then check that that domain account isn't locked up or expired.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the service account you are using to execute the replication has the appropriate rights to both your SQL servers

Answer (score 0):

Aye, check your SqlAgent account in services.msc.  Make sure it is a user with rights (in the domain and in SQL).  If that fixes it, make sure you lookup the minimum rights required before you go into production.